# Show progress with dot over svg path

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to display progress over an SVG path like that:
[image]

My current code and design shows the same SVG path with a larger width over the smaller width. :

```
return (
    <div className={style.smSemiCircleContainer}>
      {getSvg('2px')}

      <div
        className={style.smSemiCircleOverlay}
        style={{
          width: 84 + '%'
        }}
      >
        {getSvg('4px')}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
.smSemiCircleContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px;
  top: -112px;
  left: 10px;
}

.smSemiCircleOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more please that what actually you want? a simple dot on progress rest is achieved?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the dot according to the progress on the SVG path.

Comment: As i can see in picture you achieved the curved progress bar for dot try to use `pseudo` elements like `:before`

Comment: Okay, Thank you.

Comment: For that if you need assistance do let me know.. We are here to help.